# Why am I getting this callable error when I run the file?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, iot

I am recieving this callable error problem when I am trying to run my python file from the anaconda virtual env called 'weather'. I have taken this project idea from danionescu https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/danionescu . My project idea is basically an IoT Weather Station. When I try to run the 'predict.py' file after creating a weather prediction model, I get this error.

What I have already done is a bit of research. I tried using spyder but didn't get a clue. I am currently using 'JUPYTER NOTEBOOK' for earthquake prediction. But for predicting weather I am using Anaconda. 
The link for the repository is : https://github.com/danionescu0/home-automation/tree/master/weather-predict

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pymongo
import pandas
import numpy
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\Users\\sanch\\Downloads\\home-automation-master\\home-automation-master\\weather-predict')
from data_processing import AggregateEnrichProcessor
from data_processing import HistoryDatapointAugmenterProcessor
from data_processing import CleanupProcessor
from repository import DatapointsRepository
from utils import SensorTypeDatasourceMap


class PreparedDataProvider:
    MINIMUM_RAIN_TRHRESHOLD = 0.000

    def __init__(self, datapoits_repository: DatapointsRepository, sensor_type_datasource_map: SensorTypeDatasourceMap,
                 datafeatures) -> None:
        self.__datapoints_repository = datapoits_repository
        self.__sensor_type_datasource_map = sensor_type_datasource_map
        self.__datafeatures = datafeatures

    def get(self, days_behind: int, datapoints_behind: int, hour_granularity: int, data_source: str):
        sensor_types = self.__sensor_type_datasource_map.get(data_source)
        hour_group_stats = AggregateEnrichProcessor(hour_granularity, sensor_types)
        cleanup_processor = CleanupProcessor(sensor_types, self.__datafeatures)
        datapoint_augmenter_processor = HistoryDatapointAugmenterProcessor(datapoints_behind)
        extracted_data = []

        for day_behind in range(days_behind, 0, -5):
            start_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=day_behind)
            end_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=(day_behind - 5))
            datapoints = self.__datapoints_repository.get(data_source, start_date, end_date)
            extracted_data += datapoints
            print (extracted_data)
        dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(extracted_data).set_index('_id')
        dataframe = dataframe.dropna()
        dataframe = hour_group_stats.process(dataframe)
        dataframe.insert(loc=1, column='has_rain',
                         value=numpy.where(dataframe['rain_max'] > self.MINIMUM_RAIN_TRHRESHOLD, 1, 0))
        dataframe = dataframe.drop(['date'], axis=1)
        dataframe.loc['last'] = [0 for n in range(len(dataframe.columns))]
        dataframe = datapoint_augmenter_processor.process(dataframe)
        dataframe = dataframe.iloc[datapoints_behind:]

        return cleanup_processor.process(dataframe)
```

The expected result is that I should get a prediction in the form of a string on my email id when I run this script in anaconda:
python predict.py --datapoints-behind 8 --hour-granularity 6 --from-addr a_gmail_address --from-password gmail_password --to-addr a_email_destination
also when I try to print the 'extracted_data', in th output I recieve nothing.

I am getting the error as object 'module' is not callable 
The link for the files that are engaged in this error are:
https://github.com/danionescu0/home-automation/blob/master/weather-predict/graphs.py
https://github.com/danionescu0/home-automation/blob/master/weather-predict/predict.py
https://github.com/danionescu0/home-automation/blob/master/weather-predict/train.py
https://github.com/danionescu0/home-automation/blob/master/weather-predict/utils/PreparedDataProvider.py

```
    (weather) PS C:\Users\sanch\home-automation\weather-predict> python predict.py --datapoints-behind 8 --hour-granularity 6 --from-addr sanchitjain200327@gmail.com --from-password 8800533037 --to-addr sanchitjain2003@gmail.com
Using TensorFlow backend.
C:\Users\sanch\Anaconda3\envs\weather\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:523: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\sanch\Anaconda3\envs\weather\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:524: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\sanch\Anaconda3\envs\weather\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\sanch\Anaconda3\envs\weather\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\sanch\Anaconda3\envs\weather\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\sanch\Anaconda3\envs\weather\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:532: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 32, in <module>
    args['hour_granularity'], args['data_source']).tail(1)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\home-automation\weather-predict\utils\PreparedDataProvider.py", line 26, in get
    cleanup_processor = CleanupProcessor(sensor_types, self.__datafeatures)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: You need to include the full error traceback in your question, as that can help dignose the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 extracted_data = [] is an empty list.
 extracted_data += datapoints >>> here you might be making it a list of dictionaries.

 dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(extracted_data).set_index('_id')
 >>> set_index expects a column name, i think thats the mistake. there might be no column with name= '_id'.
```

Update:

if you print the keys, you will be able to see the problem. 
You are using list of dictionaries , the below code also gives the same error. it should help you.

```
import pandas
list1 = []
my_dict1 = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
my_dict2 = {'col1': [11, 12], 'col2': [13, 14]}
my_dict3 = {'col1': [21, 22], 'col2': [23, 24]}

list1 += my_dict1
list1 += my_dict2
list1 += my_dict3
d = pandas.DataFrame(list1).set_index('col1')
print(d)
```

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dr412113/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 13, in 
    d = pandas.DataFrame(list1).set_index('col1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4391, in set_index
    raise KeyError("None of {} are in the columns".format(missing))
KeyError: "None of ['col1'] are in the columns"

FYI, Just printing the data_frame.

```
d = pandas.DataFrame(list1)
print(d)

Output:

      0
0  col1
1  col2
2  col1
3  col2
4  col1
5  col2
```

Comment: Sir, there is a column in a json file of weather predict whose name is "_id".

Comment: can you add a breakpoint @https://github.com/danionescu0/home-automation/blob/master/weather-predict/utils/PreparedDataProvider.py line number 34 and print extracted_data. that should make things clear.

Comment: please print "extracted_data" and share the output.

Comment: I am getting this error now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sanch\Downloads\home-automation-master\home-automation-master\weather-predict\utils\PreparedDataProvider.py", line 6, in <module>
    from data_processing.AggregateEnrichProcessor import AggregateEnrichProcessor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_processing'

Comment: I tried whatever you said, in the output I am not getting anything

Comment: that confirms the reason for the error. If there is no output , there will be no key with "_id". hence the error.

Comment: Any idea what can I do?